# Find multiple elements in string in Python

Tags: python

my problem is that I need to find multiple elements in one string.

For example I got one string that looks like this:

```
line = if ((var.equals("INPUT")) || (var.equals("OUTPUT"))
```

and then i got this code to find everything between ' (" ' and ' ") '

```
char1 = '("'
char2 = '")'


add = line[line.find(char1)+2 : line.find(char2)]
list.append(add)
```

The current result is just:

```
['INPUT']
```

but I need the result to look like this:

```
['INPUT','OUTPUT', ...]
```

after it got the first match it stopped searching for other matches, but I need to find everything in that string that matches this search.

I also need to append every single match to the list.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """line = if ((var.equals("INPUT")) || (var.equals("OUTPUT"))"""
>>> r = re.compile(r'\("(.*?)"\)')
>>> r.findall(s)
['INPUT', 'OUTPUT']
```

The trick is to use `.*?` which is a non-greedy `*`.

Comment: This is the way to do it. +1

Comment: Thanks, im using this now.

Comment: I got one more thing, how can i get the result of findall into a variable? If i try `result = r.findall(s)` i get this error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Your code should work. Looks more like an encoding issue. You're Python 2 or Python 3? Check the type of your input. With something like `print(my_input.__class__)`

Comment: I solved it, i was reading lines from a file but forgot to assign a variable to it^^

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) because that's a perfect fit for what you're trying to achieve.

Let's examine a regular expression that does what you want:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\("([^"]+)"\)')
```

It matches the string `("` then *captures* anything that isn't a quotation mark and then matches `")` at the end.

By using it with [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) you will get all the captured groups:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: regex = re.compile(r'\("([^"]+)"\)')

In [3]: line = 'if ((var.equals("INPUT")) || (var.equals("OUTPUT"))'

In [4]: regex.findall(line)
Out[4]: ['INPUT', 'OUTPUT']
```

Comment: NB: Will not work if there's a `"` in the string that he wants to find. Non-greedy star operator `*?` is the clean way to go there.

Comment: That was intentional though

Comment: Regular experssions are not generally a good fit for [brackets matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/4050925). For this particular task it works, but it can break easily (or get messy) if doing something slightly more complicated. Just a heads up to the OP

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, this will help you.

```
line = 'if ((var.equals("INPUT")) || (var.equals("OUTPUT"))'
char1 = '("'
char2 = '")'


add = line[line.find(char1)+2 : line.find(char2)]
list.append(add)
line1=line[line.find(char2)+1:]
add = line1[line1.find(char1)+2 : line1.find(char2)]
list.append(add)
print(list)
```

just add those 3 lines in your code, and you're done

Comment: how that method will help if will be more than two `("...")` in line?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correct, than something like that is help you:

```
line = 'line = if ((var.equals("INPUT")) || (var.equals("OUTPUT"))'
items = []
start = 0
end = 0
c = 0;
while c < len(line):
    if line[c] == '(' and line[c + 1] == '"':
        start = c + 2
    if line[c] == '"' and line[c + 1] == ')':
        end = c
    if start and end:
        items.append(line[start:end])
        start = end = None
    c += 1

print(items)    # ['INPUT', 'OUTPUT']
```